# Is there a possibility to use geochart with districts in cities?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I would like to have a map of Ho Chi Minh City in Vietnam and give values to specific districts. I wonder if there is a possibility in doing so using geochart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not currently. From the docs about the `resolution` setting, there is no resolution for city districts, and the highest definition is `metros` which isn't supported outside of the US.

> 'countries' - Supported for all regions, except for US state regions.
>
> 'provinces' - Supported only for country regions and US state regions. Not supported for all countries; please test a country to see whether this option is supported.
>
> 'metros' - **Supported for the US country region and US state regions only.**

However, the different provinces of Vietnam can be used with the following code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['geochart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State', 'Value'],
    ['Bắc Giang', 1],
    ['Bắc Kạn', 2],
    ['Cao Bằng', 3],
    ['Hà Giang', 4],
    ['Lạng Sơn', 5],
    ['Phú Thọ', 6],
    ['Quảng Ninh', 7],
    ['Thái Nguyên', 8],
    ['Tuyên Quang', 9],
    ['Lào Cai', 10],
    ['Yên Bái', 11],
    ['Điện Biên', 12],
    ['Hòa Bình', 13],
    ['Lai Châu', 14],
    ['Sơn La', 15],
    ['Bắc Ninh', 16],
    ['Hà Nam', 17],
    ['Hải Dương', 18],
    ['Hưng Yên', 19],
    ['Nam Định', 20],
    ['Ninh Bình', 21],
    ['Thái Bình', 22],
    ['Vĩnh Phúc', 23],
    ['Hà Nội City', 24],
    ['Hải Phòng City', 25],
    ['Hà Tĩnh', 26],
    ['Nghệ An', 27],
    ['Quảng Bình', 28],
    ['Quảng Trị', 29],
    ['Thanh Hóa', 30],
    ['Thừa Thiên–Huế', 31],
    ['Đắk Lắk', 32],
    ['Đắk Nông', 33],
    ['Gia Lai', 34],
    ['Kon Tum', 35],
    ['Lâm Đồng', 36],
    ['Bình Định', 37],
    ['Bình Thuận', 38],
    ['Khánh Hòa', 39],
    ['Ninh Thuận', 40],
    ['Phú Yên', 41],
    ['Quảng Nam', 42],
    ['Quảng Ngãi', 43],
    ['Đà Nẵng City', 44],
    ['Bà Rịa–Vũng Tàu', 45],
    ['Bình Dương', 46],
    ['Bình Phước', 47],
    ['Đồng Nai', 48],
    ['Tây Ninh', 49],
    ['Hồ Chí Minh City', 50],
    ['An Giang', 51],
    ['Bạc Liêu', 52],
    ['Bến Tre', 53],
    ['Cà Mau', 54],
    ['Đồng Tháp', 55],
    ['Hậu Giang', 56],
    ['Kiên Giang', 57],
    ['Long An', 58],
    ['Sóc Trăng', 59],
    ['Tiền Giang', 60],
    ['Trà Vinh', 61],
    ['Vĩnh Long', 62],
    ['VN-CT', 63],
    ['VN-DN', 64]
 ]);

  var opts = {
    region: 'VN',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'provinces',
  };
  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
    document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(data, opts);
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xvdmzuLs/1/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! That has been very helpful. BTW, do you know if there is away to possibility add to Google geocharts higher resolutions? Is it open to 3rd party?

Answer (score 3):

If you notice that Ho Chi Minh City or Ha Noi are missing in this map. For example, I have to use Region Code "VN-SG" instead of "Ho Chi Minh", this take me lots of time to figure out. Here is full Vietnames Geo Chart Region :)

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['State', 'Value'],
['Bắc Giang', 1],
['Bắc Kạn', 2],
['Cao Bằng', 3],
['Hà Giang', 4],
['Lạng Sơn', 5],
['Phú Thọ', 6],
['Quảng Ninh', 7],
['Thái Nguyên', 8],
['Tuyên Quang', 9],
['Lào Cai', 10],
['Yên Bái', 11],
['Điện Biên', 12],
['Hòa Bình', 13],
['Lai Châu', 14],
['Sơn La', 15],
['Bắc Ninh', 16],
['Hà Nam', 17],
['Hải Dương', 18],
['Hưng Yên', 19],
['Nam Định', 20],
['Ninh Bình', 21],
['Thái Bình', 22],
['Vĩnh Phúc', 23],
['VN-HN', 24],
['Hải Phòng City', 25],
['Hà Tĩnh', 26],
['Nghệ An', 27],
['Quảng Bình', 28],
['Quảng Trị', 29],
['Thanh Hóa', 30],
['Thừa Thiên–Huế', 31],
['Đắk Lắk', 32],
['VN-72', 33],
['Gia Lai', 34],
['Kon Tum', 35],
['Lâm Đồng', 36],
['Bình Định', 37],
['Bình Thuận', 38],
['Khánh Hòa', 39],
['Ninh Thuận', 40],
['Phú Yên', 41],
['Quảng Nam', 42],
['Quảng Ngãi', 43],
['Đà Nẵng City', 44],
['Bà Rịa–Vũng Tàu', 45],
['Bình Dương', 46],
['Bình Phước', 47],
['Đồng Nai', 48],
['Tây Ninh', 49],
['VN-SG', 50],
['An Giang', 51],
['VN-55', 52],
['Bến Tre', 53],
['Cà Mau', 54],
['Đồng Tháp', 55],
['Hậu Giang', 56],
['Kiên Giang', 57],
['Long An', 58],
['Sóc Trăng', 59],
['Tiền Giang', 60],
['Trà Vinh', 61],
['Vĩnh Long', 62],
['VN-CT', 63],
['VN-DN', 63]]);
```

Comment: Thanks Binh! This has been helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm not from Vietnam and had no idea why some of the provinces seemed to be missing, but I got the list from Wikipedia and it seemed complete. Thanks for explaining.